# Insert Tensor into bigger tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow 1.15
I have a Tensor that contains an image with shape (Batchsize*Width*Height*3)

I have a Patch with size Batchsize*50*50*3
I want to specify a location in the original image in which the patch gets inserted.
But to make it more simple let's say I have a 1D Array with 10 elements and want to 
replace a single value at a given index
The beginning would looks like this.

```
sess = tf.Session()
array = tf.placeholder("float32",[10]) # for easier explanation a 1d array 
variable = tf.get_variable(name=var,shape=[1],intializer=init) # This variable should replace the value
index = tf.placeholder("int32",[1]) # the value on this index should be replaced
# Here The value of the image tensor at place index should be replaced with the variable

in_dict = {image: np.zeros([10],dtype="float")
           index: 4}
sess.run(...,feed_dict=in_dict)
```

tf.where needs two tensors that have the same size but my variable and array have different sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a padded smaller tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10])
x_sub = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2])
idx = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, ())


def assign_slice(x, y, idx):
  '''return x with x[r:r+len(y)] assigned values from y'''
  x_l = x.shape[0]
  y_l = y.shape[0]
  #pad the smaller tensor accordingly with shapes and index using NaNs
  y_padded = tf.pad(y, [[idx, x_l-y_l-idx]], constant_values=float('NaN'))
  #if value in padded tensor is NaN, use x, else use y
  return tf.where(tf.is_nan(y_padded), x, y_padded)


y = assign_slice(x, x_sub, idx)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x:np.ones([10]), x_sub:np.zeros([2]), idx:2}))
```

This should print `[1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]`.

Another approach might be to feed same sized tensors with a mask, i.e.:
`out = x * mask + y * (1-mask)`